# How to easily change a font-sizing from px to em for a big, existing site?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to easily change a font-sizing from `px` to `em` for a big, existing site?

Any tips to do this quickly?

Comment: Search and replace through the CSS? ;-)

Comment: Just the font sizes? What about sizes of elements themselves?

Comment: @Nivas: let’s leave that for tomorrow, we don’t want to send the poor chap completely mad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your existing stylesheet, but it’s probably not going to be quick I’m afraid (assuming you want the site to look the same after you’re done).

#### Potential Problems

When text is sized in pixels, the visual size of the text will be the same as what you put in the CSS. For example, the CSS `p {font-size: 12px;}` will result in all `<p>` tags having a font size of 12 pixels.

However, when text is sized in ems, the visual size is calculated relative to the font size of its nearest ancestor.

So, if you had the following CSS:

```
body {font-size: .625em;}

p {font-size: 1.2em;}

.header {font-size: 1.5em;}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<body>

<p>Paragraph</p>

<div class="header>
    <p>Paragraph inside header</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Then the visual font size of the *first* paragraph would be 1.2 (paragraph’s size) × .625 (body’s font size) × 16 pixels (the default root font size of all modern browsers) = **12 pixels**.

But the visual size of the *second* paragraph would be 1.2 (paragraph’s size) × 1.5 (`.header`’s size) × .625 × 16 pixels = **18 pixels**.

If you don’t have a lot HTML elements with different font sizes nested within each other, then you’re fine. But you’ll need to check that yourself in the HTML — it could be difficult to tell from the stylesheet alone, especially if it’s a big site.

#### Approach

In terms of approach, when sizing fonts in ems, it’s easiest if the design for your site doesn’t have too many different font sizes. I prefer to set the `<body>` element to the most commonly-used font size, e.g.

```
body {
    font-size: .75em;/* 12px */
}
```

Then you *only* change from that when you need to, e.g.

```
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em; /* 16px */
}
```

Otherwise you can end up sizing and resizing a lot when nesting happens. This can be particularly annoying for e.g. `<li>`s.

Of course, this approach only works if the design for the site doesn’t include lots of different font sizes.

Some people set `body` to `0.625em` because that equals `10px` (16 × 0.625 = 10), meaning for elements that don’t have an ancestor with a set font size, `1em` = `10px`, `1.1em` = `11px` and so on. Personally, I think that adds more complexity than it removes, but I’ve never done a comparison.

Either way, I find it really helpful to put the intended visual font size in comments after each use of `font-size`, as above. That way, you remember what font size the element was meant to be if it gets re-nested in the HTML.

Comment: Bump. It should be relatively easy to change this, but quite3 time consumign to deal with unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open css file
2. Search for px, look at how many
   different sizes are there
3. Decide on a conversion e.g. 10px
   =.5em,  12px=1em
4. Search/replace each size

Comment: You're ignoring 5). Regression test site and deal with the consequences of changing form an absolute to a relative unit which will not be a seamless transition.

Comment: Yeah this wont work as elements will be nested and so the em conversion will depend on at what level of the DOM hierarchy an element resides.